# Webform Protected Downloads

Tags: 6, webforms

I am trying to figure out how to use [this module](http://drupal.org/project/webform_protected_downloads).

I've downloaded it, installed it, etc. However, when I try to set up a webform, I'm not seeing anywhere where I can upload files and redirect to a link programmatically.

Where do I set this up?

I found this online, but I don't see "protected" anywhere.

> Configurations on my site:
>
> 1. Installed the modules (Webform Protected Downloads, Private Upload)
> 2. Changed 'Default Upload Privacy Setting:' to 'Public' under 'admin/settings/private_upload'
> 3. Created a Webform > attached a file
> 4. Under 'File attachments' selected 'Public'
> 5. Enabled 'Protected' under 'Protected Downloads'.
> 6. Enabled 'view uploaded files' permission for anonymous users under 'admin/user/permissions'

Comment: Have you added a File field to your webform to allow users to upload files? This module will not do that; it only adds enhancements to webforms that already allow uploads.

Comment: A file field is supported, yes, but I don't see any "protected" section, only a private section. Nor do I see where it is supposed to link the user/redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The D6 version of the module doesn't support filefield. You must use the drupal upload module. On the node edit form: Attach a file, set it to private. Switch to the tab "Protected downloads" and specify your settings there.
If you don't see the tab "Protected downloads" then it might be a bug. Consider opening an issue for this on the issue queue for the module on drupal.org.

Comment: Your're welcome. Small addition for other users that might find this question: Remember to grant the permission  "administer webform protected downloads", otherwise the tab "Protected downloads" is not available.